# My webpart event handling does not fire in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, event-handling, web-parts

I started coding something complicated and then realized my event handlers don't work, so I super simplified a button with an event handler. Please see the code below and maybe you can tell me why it doesn't fire?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace PrinterSolution
{
    [Guid("60e54fde-01bd-482e-9e3b-85e0e73ae33d")]
    public class ManageUsers : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
    {
        Button btnNew;


        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            btnNew = new Button();
            btnNew.CommandName = "New";
            btnNew.CommandArgument = "Argument";
            btnNew.Command += new CommandEventHandler(btnNew_Command);
            this.Controls.Add(btnNew);
        }

        void btnNew_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["state"] = "newstate";
        }



        //protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    this.EnsureChildControls();
        //}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. In my case the button was contained in a panel and although buttons on the parent control worked correctly the button on the child Panel control didn't.

It turns out that you need to call `EnsureChildControls` in the `OnLoad` method in the child panel to ensure that `CreateChildControls` is called early enough in the [life cycle of the page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) so that controls can respond to events. This is described briefly in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073282/button-click-event-not-getting-fired-in-webparts-when-inherited-from-other-webpar/2074423#2074423) which is where I discovered the solution to my problem.

Following this instruction I just added the following code to my panel control:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

I notice that there appears to be a lot of confusion about this issue in the forums so to demonstrate that this works I added trace statements to my code. Below are the results from the before and after cases. Note that the position of `Survey list creating child controls` moves from within the PreRender event to within the Load event.

Before:

[image: Before making the change to call EnsureChildControls in the OnLoad override]

After:

[image: After making the change to call EnsureChildCOntrols in the OnLoad override which shows the child controls being created in the correct place in the page life cycle]