# Radio buttom event in SharePoint WebPart not working

Tags: .net, sql, sharepoint, web-parts

I am trying to create a search tool. It can search and it reacts on my search button click. I have added some radio buttons the user can use to set some settings. I want the webpart to make a new search every time the radio button checked is changed but this is what I can't get to work.

I have tried to do what is told in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966928/my-webpart-event-handling-does-not-fire-in-sharepoint) but it didn't helped.

### Here is my code

```
public class HelloWorld : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart
{
    Button btn;
    TextBox textBx;
    string _myProperty = "";
    DataTable resultsDataTable = new DataTable();
    RadioButton exactSearch;
    RadioButton wildSearch;

    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
    [WebBrowsable(true)]
    [System.ComponentModel.Category("My Property Group")]
    [WebDisplayName("MyProperty")]
    [WebDescription("Meaningless Property")]
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myProperty == null)
            {
                _myProperty = "Hello SharePoint";
            }
            return _myProperty;
        }
        set { _myProperty = value; }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        textBx = new TextBox();
        textBx.Text = "";

        btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Search";

        exactSearch = new RadioButton();
        exactSearch.GroupName = "searchSetting";
        exactSearch.Checked = false;

        wildSearch = new RadioButton();
        wildSearch.GroupName = "searchSetting";
        wildSearch.Checked = true;

        //Events
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        wildSearch.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(wildSearch_CheckedChanged);

        //Adding to controls
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        this.Controls.Add(textBx);
        this.Controls.Add(exactSearch);
        this.Controls.Add(wildSearch);
    }

    void wildSearch_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        search();
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        search();
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        //Title
        writer.Write("Super Lookup Service <br/>");

        //Search block
        textBx.RenderControl(writer);
        writer.Write("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
        btn.RenderControl(writer);
        writer.Write("<br/>");
        writer.Write("Exact Search ");
        exactSearch.RenderControl(writer);
        writer.Write("&nbsp;&nbsp;");
        writer.Write("Wild Search ");
        wildSearch.RenderControl(writer);
        writer.Write("<br/><br/>");

        //Search results
        if (resultsDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            writer.Write("<b> {0} Results:</b><br/>", resultsDataTable.Rows.Count);
            foreach (DataRow row in resultsDataTable.Rows)
            {
                writer.Write("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a> ({2}) - size: {3}<br/>", row["path"].ToString(), row["title"].ToString(), row["author"].ToString(), row["Size"].ToString());
            }
        }

        else
        {
            writer.Write("<b>0 Results:</b>");
        }
    }

    private void search()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
        {
            FullTextSqlQuery query = new FullTextSqlQuery(site);
            string queryText = "";

            if (wildSearch.Checked == true)
            {
                queryText = "SELECT title, path, author, Size from Scope() where title LIKE '%" + textBx.Text + "%' order by title asc ";
            }
            else if (exactSearch.Checked == true)
            {
                queryText = "SELECT title, path, author, Size from Scope() where title = '" + textBx.Text + "' order by title asc ";
            }

            query.QueryText = queryText;
            query.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
            query.RowLimit = 3000;

            ResultTableCollection resultTables = query.Execute();
            if (resultTables.Count > 0)
            {
                ResultTable relevantResults = resultTables[ResultType.RelevantResults];
                resultsDataTable.Load(relevantResults, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when creating raddio button on OnCreateChildControl, you have to set AutoPostBack property of the radio button to true, if not it does not post back and does not fire the event.

```
wildSearch.AutoPostBack = true;
```

Comment: how can i set the property of the radio button before i have create the radio button? Didn't you ment something else?

Comment: Just got it to work. I just set the property right after i created it. And i had to set to for all radiobuttons in the group,